# Find an element's text not on screen during execution

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm learning web scraping with Selenium and to practice I'm trying to get some promotions from [this site](https://www.smiles.com.br/home):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def get_promotion():
    '''
    Web scraping process to get Smiles promotion
    '''     
    promotions = []
    chrome_options = Options()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.get('https://www.smiles.com.br/home')
    site_promotion = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'swiper-slide')  
    for promotion in site_promotion:
        promotions.append(
            { 
                'destination': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/h3').text,
                'origin': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/h4/span[2]').text,
                'diamont_value': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/div/span[2]/p[3]').text,
                'normal_value': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/div/span[2]/p[2]').text,
            }

        )
    return promotions
```

The problem is that the result didn't bring the information of the last 3 cards, as shown below:

```
[
  {'destination': 'São Paulo (GRU)', 'origin': 'Maceió (MCZ)', 'diamont_value': '17.700', 'normal_value': '19.000'}, 
  {'destination': 'Rio de Janeiro (GIG)', 'origin': 'Recife (REC)', 'diamont_value': '19.500', 'normal_value': '21.000'}, 
  {'destination': 'Brasília (BSB)', 'origin': 'Recife (REC)', 'diamont_value': '17.700', 'normal_value': '19.000'}, 
  {'destination': 'Porto Seguro (BPS)', 'origin': 'Belo Horizonte (CNF)', 'diamont_value': '13.300', 'normal_value': '14.500'}, 
  {'destination': 'Goiânia (GYN)', 'origin': 'Palmas (PMW)', 'diamont_value': '11.500', 'normal_value': '12.500'}, 
  {'destination': '', 'origin': '', 'diamont_value': '', 'normal_value': ''}, 
  {'destination': '', 'origin': '', 'diamont_value': '', 'normal_value': ''}, 
  {'destination': '', 'origin': '', 'diamont_value': '', 'normal_value': ''}
]
```

What caught my attention was the fact that when the browser opened with selenium it didn't show the last 3 cards:

[image]

The problem isn't the presence of the elements. Debugging I could see that the last 3 elements of `site_promotion` are there.

Is Selenium confused by the fact that the last 3 cards didn't appear on screen? If yes, how could I fix this?

Is there a way to grab this element's text even if they aren't appearing on the screen?

---

I tried to add `options.add_argument("--start-maximized")` but it just returned an empty promotions list.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `.text` you should use `.get_attribute('textContent')`

which would make

```
promotions.append(
    { 
        'destination': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/h3').text,
        'origin': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/h4/span[2]').text,
        'diamont_value': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/div/span[2]/p[3]').text,
        'normal_value': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/div/span[2]/p[2]').text,
    }
)
```

into

```
promotions.append(
    { 
        'destination': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/h3').get_attribute('textContent'),
        'origin': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/h4/span[2]').get_attribute('textContent'),
        'diamont_value': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/div/span[2]/p[3]').get_attribute('textContent'),
        'normal_value': promotion.find_element(By.XPATH, f'./a/div/div/div/span[2]/p[2]').get_attribute('textContent'),
    }
)
```

This [Source](https://yizeng.me/2014/04/08/get-text-from-hidden-elements-using-selenium-webdriver/) states that :

> Both the methods, getText() and getAttribute(), are used to retrieve data from an HTML element. The ***getText()*** method simply returns the ***visible text present*** between the start and end tags (which is not hidden by CSS). The getAttribute() method on the other hand identifies and fetches the key-value pairs of attributes within the HTML tags.

It seems that the values are not present as they are hidden off screen, the content may still be in the HTML but the `.text` may not correctly read it.

I had a similar issue with a site with visually hidden data even though the content was still in the HTML source.